# 2 particles in a box, perturbative solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Two particles in the ground state of a quantum box of size L with the
unperturbed wavefunctions
$\Psi_{\mathrm{nm}}^{(0)}\left(\mathrm{x}_{1}, \mathrm{x}_{2}\right)= \sin \left(\mathrm{n} \pi \mathrm{x}_{1} / \mathrm{L}\right) \sin \left(\mathrm{m} \pi \mathrm{x}_{2} / \mathrm{L}\right)$
for $0<x_{1}, x_{2}<L$ and zero otherwise. The  perturbation is
$$
\mathrm{H}_{1}=\delta\left(\mathrm{x}_{1}-\mathrm{x}_{2}\right)
$$
I'm trying to find the first order correction to the ground state wavefunction.

What I have tried is: using the following general formula,

$\left|n^{(1)}\right\rangle=\sum_{k \neq n} \frac{\left\langle k^{(0)}|V| n^{(0)}\right\rangle}{E_{n}^{(0)}-E_{k}^{(0)}}\left|k^{(0)}\right\rangle$ wrote the following equation,

$$
|\left.\psi_{n m}^{(1)}\right\rangle=\sum_{L \neq n} \sum_{k \neq m} \frac{\left\langle\psi_{k \ell}^{(0)}\left|H^{\prime}\right| \psi_{n m}^{(0)}\right\rangle |\psi_{n m}^{(0)}\rangle}{\left(E_{n m}^{(0)}-E_{k \ell}^{(0)}\right)}
$$
Then,

$$
\left\langle\psi_{k l}^{(0)}\left|H^{\prime}\right| \psi_{n m}^{(0)}\right\rangle=\int_{0}^{L} \int_{0}^{L} \sin \left(\frac{k \pi x_{1}}{L}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\ell \pi x_{2}}{L}\right) \delta\left(x_{1}-x_{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x_{1}}{L}\right) \sin \left(\frac{m \pi x_{2}}{L}\right) d_{x_1}d_{x_2}
$$

But after this part, I'm unable to decide what to do, suspecting that maybe changing $l$ and $m$ terms in the integral to $k$ and $m$ respectively yields square sin terms but that gives me confusion about why shouldn't I use directly $\sin^4(kx)$ term by changing all the dummy variables.

Comment: Remember $\int dx f(x) \delta(x-y) = f(y)$